# How to access a parent paragraph twig file from a child node twig file?

Tags: 8, theming

In my bootstrap theme, I am trying to make the id of the paragraph the same as an attribute for each of the child nodes, so an accordion will work properly. I have tried looking at doing it through hooks, but I can't seem to access the paragraph data from my node hook.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hook_preprocess_paragraph` hook to set the same id to all child nodes, in the below code snippet example all child nodes will have `paragraph-PARAGRAPH-ID` as id.

```
use Drupal\Component\Utility\Html;
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function myModule_preprocess_paragraph(&$variables) {
  $paragraph = $variables['paragraph'];
  $identifier = Html::cleanCssIdentifier('paragraph-' . $paragraph->id());
  $variables['attributes']['id'] = $identifier;
}
```

Comment: How would I put the paragraph id in a different attribute like "data-parent"  in the child node?

Comment: try with `$variables['attributes']['data-parent'] = $identifier;`  instead of `$variables['attributes']['id'] = $identifier;` .

Comment: I know I can do something like $variables['var_name'] to have it be a variable in the paragraph twig file. How would I do this to get the variable (in my case paragraph id) inside the children node twig files too?